# numpy: find all occurences of elements from one table in another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-indexing

I have a problem of translating elements in a numpy array according to a translation table given. Say I have a 2D translation table trTab, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
trTab = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5,
                  [5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 4]])
```

where `trTab[0, :]` holds all possible ids (integers), while `trTab[1, :]` their translations that will be used later. The ids in both rows of `trTab` are unique. Then I need to translate all ids in the first column of a frame numpy array, say

```
frame = np.array([[0, ...],
                  [3, ...],
                  [5, ...],
                  [1, ...]])
```

so that it would now be equal to `[[5, ...], [1, ...], [4, ...], [2, ...]]`, i.e. `0->5`, `3->1`, `5->4`, and `1->2`.

`frame` can be of different number of rows, in fact I'll need to translate a long sequence of frames. The ids in `frame` 0'th column do not have to be in order, and not all possible ids need to be used.

Is there any simple and fast method of translating each such frame array according to the given `trTab` not by simple looping over all `fr[:, 0]` values? Looping takes much too much time in case of few thousand frames to be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `trTab` first line and `frame` first column are always numbers, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import subtract as s
fancy_indices = np.absolute(s.outer(frame[:,0],trTab[0,:])).argmin(axis=1)
frame[:,0] = trTab[1,:][fancy_indices]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something essential, but why not simply write: `frame[:,0] = trTab[1,:][frame[:,0]]`? I get the same result either way, and the third row seems redundant.

Comment: If you do `frame[:,0]=trTab[1,:]` the new values of the first column in `frame` will be in the order of the second line in `trTab`. The fancy indexing using the `translate` array will take the right elements in the the second line of `trTab`

Comment: Did you include the last part of my code? If I run `frame= np.array([[0,1,5],[3,2,4],[5,3,3],[1,4,2]]), frame[:,0] = trTab[1,:][frame[:,0]]` I get a translated first column with the correct ordering. Or maybe I'm just being dense.

Comment: Now I understood. In this case it would work if the first column in `frame` is a number from `0` to `trTab.shape[1]-1`, but what if he decides to use a number `100` for example, it would raise an `IndexError`

Comment: But that would amount to trying to translate something that is not in the translation table. With your original solution, you would get a translation but the wrong one (or rather a translation of something not found in the translation table). See: `frame= np.array([[0,1,5],[3,2,4],[5,3,3],[6,4,2]]), translated = np.absolute(s.outer(frame[:,0],trTab[0,:])).argmin(axis=1), frame[:,0] = trTab[1,:][translated]` where 6 -> 4 even though it's not in the trTab.

Comment: but translated gives just the indices, not the translated values. I collect them using `trTab[1,:][translated]`... here there will be no index out of range...

Comment: @fileunderwater I changed the variable name in the answer to avoid this confusion...

Comment: ok, but it is still giving me the same undefined translations without warnings if I e.g. use: `trTab=np.array([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,2,3,1,0]]), frame= np.array([[0,1,5],[3,2,4],[5,3,3],[6,4,2]]), fancy_indices = np.absolute(s.outer(frame[:,0],trTab[0,:])).argmin(axis=1), frame[:,0] = trTab[1,:][fancy_indices]` where both 5 & 6 are translated to 0.

Comment: but you build the array wrong. All the items in the first column of frame must be in the first line of trTab... see the OP's question

Comment: You are right. I just felt uneasy about getting undefined translations without any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
dic={0:5,1:2,2:3,3:1,4:0,5:4}
frame= np.array([[0,1],[3,2],[5,3],[1,4]])
frame[:,0]=[dic[x] for x in frame[:,0]]
```